# Retrieve user tweets in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, twitter, windows-store-apps

How can I retrieve all tweets for specific twitter user "@username" in windows store apps?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably consider using an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to make a call to the Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Tweeter Wrapper around,

Checkout this wrapper : https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

> TweetSharp is a Twitter API library that greatly simplifies the task
>   of adding Twitter to your desktop, web, and mobile applications. You
>   can build simple widgets, or complex application suites using
>   TweetSharp. The second version, a rewrite, was designed to be lighter,
>   faster, and more intuitive than the original. You write fewer lines of
>   code, make fewer decisions, and get better results. Visual Studio T4
>   templates are employed to automatically generate new API methods from
>   a simple text-based DSL.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a tutorial about that a couple of days ago. Take a look:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599505/Databind-Twitter-XML-Feed-in-Windows-8

Should explain it :)